# Twitter Bootstrap vs jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using jQuery UI for some basic page enhancements. Button and input styling and modal dialog boxes. Now I've come across Bootstrap and it looks pretty good.

Has anyone any experience of going from using jQuery UI to Bootstrap?  This what I am thinking to do but before I do this I'd like to be aware of what problems I could face.

Comment: One possible solution that may have not been available when this was asked... Addy Osmani and his team have been working on merging of the two -- if you're stuck between them, check out and maybe you can get everything you want!  - http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/

Comment: How to update (2014!) answers?  Can any one start a bounty here?

Comment: From Bootstrap website -- "Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences." -- Good grief.

Answer (score 134):

I have on several projects.

The biggest difference in my opinion

- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) is fallback safe, it works correctly and looks good in old browsers, where [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is based on CSS3 which basically means GREAT in new browsers, not so great in old
- Update frequency: Bootstrap is getting some great big updates with awesome new features, but sadly they might break previous code, so you can't just install bootstrap and update when there is a new major release, it basically requires a lot of new coding
- jQuery UI is based on good html structure with transformations from JavaScript, while Bootstrap is based on visually and customizable inline structure. (calling a widget in JQUERY UI, defining it in Bootstrap)

So what to choose?

That always depends on the type of project you are working on. Is cool and fast looking widgets better, or are your users often using old browsers?

I always end up using both, so I can use the best of both worlds.

Here are the links to both frameworks, if you decide to use them.

1. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)
2. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: -Thanks for taking the time to answer. My needs are for something working on IE9 or the other later version browsers that have pretty good CSS3 support. Bootstrap is starting to look good for me. One question. I am using ASP.MVC. I noticed something about needing less. Will Boostrap work okay with the Microsoft ASP MVC platform? Where does "less" fit in?

Comment: You can compile the less files to .css files. Building the bootstrap (using make), will create ready to use CSS files. In that way you don't need to use less.

Comment: LESS is a css framework. It is in no way needed for using Boostrap (they have a regular CSS / JS version), but with LESS you can easily make variabels in CSS (change colors etc), make it dependent, have functions. See here: http://lesscss.org/ and there is a BETA version for a compiler in .NET see: http://www.dotlesscss.org/

Comment: @Jessica Just another note: you can use Bootstrap fine with MVC, in fact, you can install it from Nuget and get the CSS/JS installed in your project for you. You would just have to update your _layout file.

Comment: **How do you even use the "best of both worlds"?** The closest I've gotten is by using [jQueryUI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) (basically a jQueryUI theme) but still it's designed for Bootstrap 1.4, not 2.0, and there's clashes when trying to use JS for buttons, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your third bullet point?

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 ill try! Example: in bootstrap you write all the classes on the button element (ie. `button button-primary button-small`, where in jQueryUI you assign a element to be a button ie just add "btn" and then through JS you make it a button `$(".btn").button()`. This means that in Bootstrap you define it in HTML, and in jQueryUI you define it in JS. Negatives on Bootstrap is you need to edit your HTML if you update/change something(ie. Bootstrap versions) where jQueryUI you just need to change your JS which is often easier. There is positives and negatives with both! :)

Answer (score 73):

Having used both, Twitter's Bootstrap is a superior technology set. Here are some differences,

- **Widgets**: jQuery UI wins here. The date widget it provides is immensely useful, and Twitter Bootstrap provides nothing of the sort.
- **Scaffolding**: Bootstrap wins here. Twitter's grid both fluid and fixed are top notch. jQuery UI doesn't even provide this direction leaving page layout up to the end user.
- **Out of the box professionalism**: Bootstrap using CSS3 is leagues ahead, jQuery UI looks dated by comparison.
- **Icons**: I'll go tie on this one. [Bootstrap has nicer icons imho](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) than [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), but I don't like the terms one bit, *Glyphicons Halflings are normally not available for free, but an arrangement between Bootstrap and the Glyphicons creators have made this possible at no cost to you as developers. As a thank you, we ask you to include an optional link back to Glyphicons whenever practical.*
- **Images & Thumbnails**: [goes to Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#images), jQuery UI doesn't even help here.

Other notes,

- It's important to understand how these two technologies compete in the spheres too. There is a lot of overlap, but if you want simple scaffolding and fixed/fluid creation Bootstrap isn't another technology, it's the best technology. If you want any single widget, jQuery UI probably isn't even in the top three. Today, jQuery UI is mainly just a toy for consistency and proof of concept for a client-side widget creation using a unified framework.

Answer (score 34):

You can use both with relatively few issues. Twitter Bootstrap uses jQuery 1.7.1 (as of this writing), and I can't think of any reasons why you cannot integrate additional Jquery UI components into your HTML templates.

I've been using a combination of HTML5 Boilerplate & Twitter Bootstrap built at Initializr.com.  This combines two awesome starter templates into one great starter project.  Check out the details at http://html5boilerplate.com/ and http://www.initializr.com/  Or to get started right away, go to http://www.initializr.com/, click the "Bootstrap 2" button, and click "Download It".  This will give you all the js and css you need to get started.

And don't be scared off by HTML5 and CSS3.  Initializr and HTML5 Boilerplate include polyfills and IE specific code that will allow all features to work in IE 6, 7 8, and 9.

The use of LESS in Twitter Bootstrap is also optional.  They use LESS to compile all the CSS that is used by Bootstrap, but if you just want to override or add your own styles, they provide an empty css file for that purpose.

There is also a blank js file (script.js) for you to add custom code.  This is where you would add your handlers or selectors for additional jQueryUI components.

Comment: Great answer. Quick question tough, what does jquery ui really offer than is not included in twitter bootstrap and its plugins?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. As far as js widgets, jQuery UI has a datepicker and slider, which are not included in Bootstrap.  Also jqUI includes interactions and effects, such as drag-and-drop, show/hide animations, class toggling, and several more.  Combining jqUI's interactions with Bootstrap's layout components can be a very powerful combination.

Comment: One issue to watch out for; both projects define $.fn.button in incompatible ways.

Answer (score 27):

We have used both and we like Bootstrap for its simplicity and the pace at which it's being developed and enhanced. The problem with jQuery UI is that it's moving at a snail's pace. It's taking years to roll out common features like Menubar, Tree control and DataGrid which are in planning/development stage for ever. We waited waited waited and finally given up and used other libraries like ExtJS for our product http://dblite.com.

Bootstrap has come up with quite a comprehensive set of features in a very short period of time and I am sure it will outpace jQuery UI pretty soon.

So I see no point in using something that will eventually be outdated...

Comment: Everything will eventually be outdated. There is no point in doing anything.

Comment: True, we just need to pick the one which we think will hold its ground for longer.

Comment: Nah, you just need to pick the one that's going to bring in the money from your clients. Once you get it working, it should continue to work for a while, even if it falls out of style, so the only real concern is the money.